# Multiple DataSource instances

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Is it less-than-ideal to have multiple `DataSource` instances when using JDBC?

If I have a base class that has various subclasses that all use a single static instance of `DataSource` (if it matters, I'm using the Postgres driver), I imagine that is ideal because there is a single source for them to get their connections and I'll see a bigger benefit from pooling connections.

The other option is to have each subclass have its own `DataSource` instance, which I imagine is not ideal.

Just my guess though. Any more info would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no good reason to have multiple DataSource instances if you only target a single database.

Comment: of course , if all subclasses needs to access same DB through same data source then better option is what you are trying to do...however if any of the subclass needs separate data source other than postgress then 2nd option is preferable..i think in your case its clear to go with first option..